# Historical values for the German "Sonntagsfrage"?

Tags: data-request, germany, elections

In Germany, there are several surveys on voter's preference ("If there were an election next sunday, which party would you vote for"), the so-called "Sonntagsfrage".

Are historical values available? I found 
[this graphical data](http://www.sonntagsfrage-aktuell.de/), but I am looking for numbers, ideally under an open license.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the [Overview of the Allensbach Institute](http://www.ifd-allensbach.de/studien-und-berichte/sonntagsfrage/gesamt.html), which has data at least for the current legislative period. The data can be easily scraped, see for example my [R script](http://pastebin.com/Vpzn7gqV).

This helps a bit, but if you have another answer, I will accept and upvote yours.

Comment: What is the license of this one?

Answer (score 3):

[Wahlrecht.de](http://www.wahlrecht.de/umfragen/) provides a good list of results of the major survays.
Together with the [wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/) it should give you all the available survey data.